# PCL Framework Targets Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, portable-class-library

I have created a new PCL project for my new project in Visual Studio 2013. However, whenever I try install the portable mvvmlight libraries from nuget I get the following error.

```
install-package : Could not install package 'Portable.MvvmLightLibs 4.2.30.1'.
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+sl40+wp80+win', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author. 
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package portable.mvvmlightlibs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

These are the target frameworks I have selected :
[image: Target Frameworks]

So as you can see I dont have Silverlight 4 selected, so not sure why its tryin?g to find a match for a project that has it?

Can anyone help me out with this, or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks 
Mauro

Comment: According to the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.MvvmLightLibs) the PCL is targeting Silverlight 5. Will the package install properly if you check the `Silverlight 5` checkbox?

Comment: The strange thing is that if I check Silverlight 5 and close the dialog and then re-open it, it is unchecked. The only time Silverlight 5 stays checked is when I select Xamarin.Android & Xamarin.iOS. However, if I select those the package then says that I cannot install it as there is nothing matching the mono items then. Not sure why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

In the targeting dialog, select Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android in addition to the three other frameworks you have targeted.

Then, make sure you've updated to the latest version of NuGet, and try to install the package again.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have the latest Nuget 2.8 and when I select Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android I get the following error :

Comment: @Mauro: What error?  It looks like it didn't paste correctly.  If necessary edit your original question to include it.